# Recursive Streaming API

Tags: java, recursion, graph-theory

I'm currently working on a small graph theory algorithm, which uses a recursive Depth-First Search.
Since it's recursive, I'm asking myself, if I should use the Stream API to perform such a task or use Iterators and for each Loops.
This is my code:

```
private void processNext(Node node) {
//METHOD A
    for (Node neighbour : node) {
        if (!connectedNodes.contains(neighbour)) {
            connectedNodes.add(neighbour);
            processNext(neighbour);
        }
    }
//OR METHOD B
    node.getNodes().stream().filter(not(connectedNodes::contains)).forEach(e -> {
        connectedNodes.add(e);
        processNext(e);
    });
//OR METHOD C
    node.getNodes().stream().forEach(e -> {
        if (!connectedNodes.contains(e)) {
            connectedNodes.add(e);
            processNext(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Method A and C will work 100% intended, but I'm not sure about B...
Does the filter method in the streaming API filter non matching objects out before foreach or while foreach? (Do B and C the exact same thing?)

And which Method will be the fastest?

Any help is apreciated!

Comment: Only way to know definitively which is fastest is profiling. And of course, you can use Unit Tests to check for correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Method B and C work exactly the same!
Not sure if the iterator way is faster, but since B requires less space, I'm going for that one!